# JavaScript Input text per value attribute in onClick

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to `input` the number which I click to the `text box` from the `attribute` value present on that number.

If I click number **1** then the value is number **1** and so on.

This is my script:

```js
function myFunc() {
  var dadada = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < dadada.length; i++) {
    var de = dadada[i].getAttribute("value");
  }
  document.getElementById("text_id").value = de;

}
```

```html
<div id="xxx">
  <a class="list-group-item" href="#" value="1" onclick="myFunc()">1</a>
  <a class="list-group-item" href="#" value="2" onclick="myFunc()">2</a>
  <a class="list-group-item" href="#" value="3" onclick="myFunc()">3</a>
  <a class="list-group-item" href="#" value="4" onclick="myFunc()">4</a> 
this value: <input type="text" id="text_id" value="">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the value of the clicked link. Get all the `<a>` in javascript using `querySelectorAll()` and then loop through them and `addEventListener` to them.

Use the eventObject `e` and get the attribute `value` of the clicked link

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.list-group-item');
items.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', e => myFunc(e))
})

function myFunc(e) {
    document.getElementById("text_id").value =e.target.getAttribute('value')
}
```

```html
<div id="xxx">
<a  class="list-group-item" href="#" value="1">1</a> 
<a  class="list-group-item" href="#"  value="2">2</a> 
<a  class="list-group-item" href="#"  value="3">3</a> 
<a  class="list-group-item" href="#"  value="4">4</a>    
this value: <input type="text" id="text_id" value="">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this by passing the dom element directly to the function like this:

```js
function myFunc(elem) {
  var de = elem.getAttribute("value");
  document.getElementById("text_id").value = de;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<div id="xxx">
  <a class="list-group-item" href="#" value="1" onclick="myFunc(this)">1</a>
  <a class="list-group-item" href="#" value="2" onclick="myFunc(this)">2</a>
  <a class="list-group-item" href="#" value="3" onclick="myFunc(this)">3</a>
  <a class="list-group-item" href="#" value="4" onclick="myFunc(this)">4</a> 
  <br/><br/>
  This value: <input type="text" id="text_id" value="">
```

Comment: thanks for reply... i try this work in here... but i try in https://jsfiddle.net/omz92aun/  not working....

Comment: js fiddle by default add all js on load which is causing the issue. But if we update it to put the js in body tag at bottm, it works fine, like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/a6skmc3z/). For info about this [here](https://docs.jsfiddle.net/panels-settings#javascript-panel).

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer below

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
  <a  class="list-group-item" value="1" href="#" >1</a> 
  <a  class="list-group-item" value="2" href="#" >2</a> 
  <a  class="list-group-item" value="3" href="#" >3</a> 
  <a  class="list-group-item" value="4" href="#" >4</a>
</div>

this value: <input type="text" id="text_id" value="">
```

**Javascript**

```
var parent = document.querySelector("#parent");
var input = document.querySelector("#text_id");

parent.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        input.value = e.srcElement.getAttribute("value");
})
```

Mine is a bit different because it uses event delegation, ie. you only need to listen to parent elements click rather than each anchor element's click. I personally feel it's a cleaner approach and efficient.

Comment: thanks for reply.. but i want to get value  in attribute value for input to text form ..

Comment: Updated my answer.